# Where should I create a model instance for a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I am new to MVVM. As far as I understand, I must avoid using model code inside a view struct.

In my case, I have 2 views, MainView and ChildView. MainView doesn't have a ViewModel. But ChildView has a ViewModel(e.g. ChildViewModel). Since the ChildViewModel is used only in ChildView, so I didn't register the model instance on EnvironmentObject or I didn't pass the instance to MainView, because MainView doesn't use the model at all.

I think, the best way is that ChildView creates its own instance of the model by itself like below. But I am not sure whether it is ok or not. Does this break the rules of MVVM?

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var childViewModel = ChildViewModel()

    var body: some View { ... }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this break the rules of MVVM?

No, it does not, because MVVM about "responsibility separation", and provided pattern is exactly separates View & ViewModel. Moreover it follows "dependency injection" rule as well, because you can use and

`ChildView() // with default model`

and

`ChildView(childViewModel: ChildViewModel(...)) // some specific model`

Answer (score 3):

I diagree with accepted answer. I'll provide my arguments.

MVVM is NOT about having an object called view model. Most MVVM devs are just doing it for the sake for having an object called view model.

> because MVVM about "responsibility separation"

What design pattern is NOT about responsibility separation?

Why do you think SwiftUI SDK design does not provide responsibility separation?

> I must avoid using model code inside a view struct

First view struct is not a view, it's a model that conforms to view.

E.g.; `struct Model: View`

This is designed so that you can do model -> view binding (and optionally view -> model binding) easily.

There are annotations like `@State`, `@StateObject` built specifically to support it.

E.g.; re-renders when `@State` changes, compiler checks to prevent access `@State` object from outside `struct Model: View`.

In other words, `struct Model: View` is *the* place to write model codes! By design!

Note that it is `struct Model`, not `class Model`. MVVM does not take value type into consideration. So instead of taking advantage of the immutability of value type, MVVM has you believe that a separate model in a **reference type** is a good idea? It is not.

I'm going to say this again. **A model in a REFERENCE type for "responsibility separation".**

There are legacy reasons that you have to create a separate View Model. It depends on how the binding is designed. It's entirely feasible that you need a separate view model for binding to work in some common language.

But Swift is not some common language.

I don't know why MVVM devs think SwiftUI SDK creators are idiots and don't know anything about MVVM. The truth is that, SwiftUI has a binding design so efficient, you don't need a separate view model to describe binding.

Hell, even I can see that you now have full advantage of binding and automatic view update from value type model, the most iconic MVVM features, without the overheads of manually creating a separate view model. And I'm not a MVVM dev.

SwiftUI makes view model by default. I've seen attempts of building a view model on top of it times and times again. They all failed miserably, because view model is dead-weight now.

You don't need it, and in fact you lose SDK support when you use it.

Or think of it this way. SwiftUI removes UIViewController.

Do you see MVC developers come out and insist you create a separate Controller object?

The same argument applies. E.g.;

> because MVC is about "responsibility separation", and provided pattern
> is exactly separates View & Control. Moreover it follows "dependency
> injection" rule as well

Don't let these abstract words confuse you. There are basic principles that apply to everything.

To your question, it's an inefficient form of MVVM. ChildView should be your model.
And that is more MVVM than what these MVVM devs told you.

E.g.;

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @State var value: Value 
    @StateObject var resource: JSON
    var body: some View { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not violates the MVVM pattern. If your main view needs to pass some parameters to child view it should do so by using init parameters. However, one thing to note is, everytime you navigate to child view from your main view, a new instance of ChilViewModel would be created. In use cases, where this is not acceptable, a view model is created in the parent view and passed on to the child view to maintain the same instance everytime a user navigates to child view. Both do not violate the MVVM pattern. Hope that answers your question.